# Number [n,k]-linear codes with one fixed vector

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

I need to find the number of $[n,k]$-linear binary codes with one fixed codeword `x` (non zero) in it.

So I guess, I need to count the number of $k$-dimensional linear codes with vector $x$ **in basis**:

We have $2^n-2$ codewords (excluded $0$ and $x$) to choose as a basis vector.
if we add vectors in basis (with vector $x$ in it) subsequently, we will get:

*the number of $k$-linear codes with $x$ **in basis*** = $\frac{\prod 2^n - 2^i,i=1..k-1}{\prod 2^n - 2^i, i=1,..k-1}$

I think something is wrong here.

Can I just say that required number = the number of $k$-linear codes with $x$ **in basis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\span}{\operatorname{span}}$Let $C$ be a $[n,k]$-linear binary code containing a fixed codeword $0 \ne x \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$.
Then $\span(x)$ is a subspace of $C$, so $C = \span(x) + V$ ($ = \{ ax + b \mid a \in \mathbb{F}_2, b \in V \}$) for some $(k-1)$-dimensional subspace $V \le \mathbb{F}_2^n$ not containing $\span(x)$.

As $V \cap \span(x) = 0$ and $\span(x)$ is $1$-dimensional, there are as many ways to choose $V$ as there are to choose a $(k-1)$-dimensional subspace of a $(n-1)$-dimensional space (think of it as "choosing the dimensions other than $\span(x)$").
The number of ways to choose a $(k-1)$-dimensional subspace out of a $(n-1)$-dimensional space is the [q-binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) (with $q=2$),

$$
\binom{n-1}{k-1}_2
= \frac{
    (1 - 2^{n-1})
    (1 - 2^{n-2})
    \cdots
    (1 - 2^{n-k+1})
}{
    (1 - 2)
    (1 - 2^2)
    \cdots
    (1 - 2^{k-1})
}.
$$

So, given a fixed $0 \ne x$, there are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}_2$ binary $[n,k]$-linear codes containing $x$.

Comment: Here are some [lecture notes](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~levine/18.312/alg-comb-lecture-13.pdf) (not mine) showing that there are $\binom{n}{k}_q$ ways to choose a $k$-dimensional subspace of a $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$.